# Boot Kali Linux through a image in a partition

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

**What I want:** I want to multiboot windows 10 and Kali Linux without touching the partiton table, so I am trying to install Kali Linux in a .img located in my existing windows partitions. Then I will instruct grub to create a loopback and boot from that image.

**What I did:** So, to install Kali Linux to that .img file, I first created the IMG using `dd`.
Then I started the install-disk and proceeded to load the `fuse` and `ntfs` modules.

Then I opened a new terminal(`Ctrl+Alt+F2`) and mounted the partition in which IMG is located.

**Problems:**

1. I can't run `losetup` in the terminal
2. Say somehow I installed it to the IMG, created the loopback device in grub, loaded the `vmlinuz` then, I think it won't be able to load rest of the system files as it requires `root=/dev/sdX` as a boot parameter. So, can I somehow modify the `vmlinuz` or `initrd.img` to mount a partition and run `losetup` and after that read the `root=/dev/loopX` to load the rest of the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i achieved it :

1. Start the installation process
2. Continue till the "Partition Disks" step and hit "Go Back"
3. Start another terminal ( `Alt+Ctrl+F2`) and mount the filesystem in which image is stored (say at `/mnt`).
4. run `ln -s /mnt/path/to/image /dev/sdb` to fool the Install System.
5. Switch to previous Terminal.(`Alt+Ctrl+F5` in my case)
6. Continue installation from "Detect Disks" Step. `/mnt/path/to/image` should be there, Select It.
7. Use it as some filesystem (`ext4` in my case) and set mount point as `/`, do not select swap for now and hit finish.
8. Finish the installation as usual.
9. Now, reboot to "Kali Live" and open a terminal
10. Mount the filesystem in which image is stored (say at `/mnt`). Also mount the image, eg:`mount -o loop /mnt/path/to/image /myimg`
11. Chroot into the image: `chroot /myimg`
12. Modify the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and add `loop`.
13. Modify `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local`:
        - empty the present `mountroot()` and fill with:

`mkdir /root2
mount -t <type of fs inwhich image is stored> /dev/sdXY /root2
mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw /root2/path/to/image ${rootmnt}`

14. Run `update-initramfs`
15. Add a grub entry:

`loopback loop (hdX,Y)/path/to/image
linux (loop)/vmlinuz
initrd (loop)/initrd.img`

16. Done !!